# Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

**Introduction**
I deployed my application [Here](http://insideminds.gear.host/) on GearHost, everything went well. I clearly understand that its database access issue within application because some of the pages are accessible where no db connection is required like about-us.

**Error** : Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows authentication.

**Connection String**

```
<add name="IMConn" connectionString="Data Source=mssql3.gear.host;Initial Catalog=IMDb;Integrated Security=True;user id=****;password=******"  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

If someone have idea about that problem, please help.Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `IntegratedSecurity = false;`

```
<add name="IMConn" connectionString="Data Source=mssql3.gear.host;Initial Catalog=IMDb;Integrated Security=False;user id=****;password=******"  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Comment: @SuhailMumtazAwan This is a workaround, not a solution